# A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface

Tags: typescript, methods, compiler-errors, this

I'm trying to define a class where one of the constructor parameter property declares and initializes a public member of type `(this: this) => string` and I'm getting a `A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface` error.

This doesn't generate and error:

```js
interface Foo {
    name: string; 
    isLocked: boolean;
    destination: string;
    description: (this: this) => string; 
}

const foo: Foo = {
    name: 'newdoor',
    isLocked: true,
    destination: 'someroom',
    description: function(this) {
        if(this.isLocked) return 'true'
        else return 'false'
    }
}
```

But this does:

```js
class Bar {
    constructor(
        public name: string, 
        public isLocked: boolean,
        public destination: string,
        public description: (this: this) => string
    ) {}    
}

const bar = new Bar(
    'newdoor',
    true,
    'someroom',
    function(this) {
        if(this.isLocked) return 'true'
        else return 'false'
    }
)
```

Can someone explain why I'm getting this error even though I am indeed using the `this` type in a non-static member of a class? Also, if this is by design and there is a reason for this error, what is the work around in order to be able to create a class instance and supply it with a member function that has access to the class instance.

**Update**

As explained in the provided answers, it seems that the use of `this` is not allowed in a constructor parameter property. But this leaves the question, how then, can I create a class instance, where one of the property parameters declares and initializes a member that is a function that needs access to the instance's other members?

If I do this:

```js
class Bar {
    constructor(
        public name: string, 
        public isLocked: boolean,
        public destination: string,
        public description: () => string
    ) {}    
}

const bar = new Bar(
    'newdoor',
    true,
    'someroom',
    function() {
        if(this.isLocked) return 'true'
        else return 'false'
    }
)
```

I then get a `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation` error. This is valid JavaScript code and does what I expect it to do. What is the proper TypeScript way to code this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is misleading and I don't know why the first example doesn't generate an error. But your problem in the second example is actually that you are trying to use `this` as a type describing the value `this`. In the signature you have type the `this` parameter to be of the type it will be. In your case it would have to be

```
(this: Bar) => string
```

Also `this` parameters are fake parameters that only tell TypeScript the type `this` will have in the function body. It is not a parameter you would pass to as an argument. Read about it in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters).

You can actually omit the `this` parameter from the function you are passing when you create a new instance because TypeScript can infer the type of `this` from the function signature in the class constructor definition.

**Update**

> As explained in the provided answers, it seems that the use of this is not allowed in a constructor parameter property.

Apparently my answer was not clear, sorry. Of course this allowed. But you were trying to do this:

```
(this: this) => string
```

That tells TypeScript that `this` (on the left) in the function body is of type `this` (on the right). But there is no type called `this` in TypeScript and it is not allowed to declare one because it is a reserved keyword. As I said above you have to declare `this` to be of type `Bar`.

Here is the full example:

```
class Bar {
    constructor(
        public name: string, 
        public isLocked: boolean,
        public destination: string,
        public description: (this: Bar) => string
    ) {}    
}

const bar = new Bar(
    'newdoor',
    true,
    'someroom',
    function() {
        if(this.isLocked) return 'true'
        else return 'false'
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Please look at my updated question for a follow-up question.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks to your answer I also better understand what the docs are talking about. I was confused because I thought that by doing `this: Bar` we were saying that `this` was referring to the static side of Bar.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following TypeScript snippet:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 3;
    function b(prop = this.a) { }

    class B {
      constructor(private a: string, b = this.a) { }
      // would/might transpile to ES5 if it wasn't blocked by TS:
      // var self = this;
      // function B(a, b) {
      //   this.a = a;
      //   this.b = typeof b === 'undefined' ? self.a : b;
      // }
    }

    function C(a: (this: this) => string) { }
  }
}
```

As used as parameter default where `b` is defined, `this` refers to the instance of `A`. So `prop` defaults to 3. Since `b` is declared as function and not a class, it's implied intent is to not have it's own instance that could be referred to by `this`, so TypeScript let's this slide (even though it's still confusing).

Now for the declaration of `class B`: even though property `a` is declared on `B`, `b` would be `3` as defined on `A` (if TypeScript didn't throw an error for using `this` in constructor parameters). But in this case you're explicitly in the context of class `B` constructor, where you might expect `this` to refer to the instance of `B`, where it in fact would refer to `A`. So TypeScript puts a stopper on this kind of crazy confusion/ambiguity and disallows usage of `this` entirely in constructor parameters (it would be especially crazy when you consider how TypeScript constructor field declarations - `constructor(private a)`- are thrown into the mix).

Finally, looking at the declaration of `C` - the most basic version of class declaration in JS - it's somewhat hard to reason what `this` even means in the context. It's very ambiguous and not even defined by TypeScript, but that is essentially what your `Bar` constructor is attempting.

Having established how JavaScript treats `this` in function parameters, I hope it is clear why TypeScript tries to reduce any ambiguity surrounding `this`, especially given it's extended usage a type/parameter:

The `this` type is exclusively a utility for member functions - as `description` is on `Foo`. It is a polymorphic type that allows methods on base classes to return the exact derived type of a derived class, if they are returning an instance of themselves (as for method chaining):

```
class A {
  doStuff(): this {
    // doStuff
    return this;
  }
}

class B extends A { }

(new B()).doStuff(); // returns type B
```

Usage of the `this` parameter, which is "fake", allows the define the function execution context, for example in an event handler:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(this: Window) {

});
```

In the compiled JavaScript you would just have:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { });
```

So to conclude: `function(this: this) { ... }` is redundant as used in your interface `Foo` (though technically valid TypeScript), and `constructor(private a: (this: this) => number)` is undefined behavior/incorrect usage of the `this` type/parameter, thus the error you receive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Please look at my updated question for a follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

> "This is valid JavaScript code and does what I expect it to do. What is the proper TypeScript way to code this."

TypeScript is not actually a super-set of JavaScript, and there are many features which the devs have explicitly stated they wont support.  This could easily be one of them.

Here is the best way forwards I have found:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJQOYGdkG8BQyRyWA9gLYQBKEMAXMnCAJ4DcyA9B8gO7BYALGAFcANqObIwzAA4RSMKQP74AvvnwJRcLDlR5CxBKRBYwUYQjCkoACjiYsDdNgCUBYp6X8AdFFrIALyMjj5klDQwrIZe3lh+tD4wpKS2rtGeqtExyDLCAEaiwAjIyamueOo5MlCkkFYQACbIAPr+9IwsGcR5hcXIGBBgyO1pBrFE-mDCUCBxPm0BOlKy8opgyljdROqevUUlWEMjtLYAbnCiFR4TwIrnl8igZkxICvPGpuaW1lBBgcF4KIjtcchMlLUeMgQBAoQBRKC1OwAAwAkiALkVmtI5Mj0mDiLsJhtfItFMFMdtkOoqhotDocAAhZAQAAekBAjT04x6BQOyHyDjGuCJRE+ZgsVhs9kczkcoPBWGEcjsDjcVM8JPi7SSKTSGuIWoSMB8grs+MyanwQA)

```
interface Args {
    someRef: any; // wishfully typeof this
}

class A {
    constructor(args: Args){
        this.ref = args.someRef;
        this.ref.foo();
    };

    public foo() {}

    protected _ref: any;
    public get ref() {
        return this._ref as typeof this;
    }
    public set ref(val) {
        if (val instanceof this.constructor === false) {
            throw new Error(`Invalid type`);
        }
        this._ref = val;
    }
}



class B extends A {
    public bar() {}
    constructor(args: Args) {
        super(args);
        this.ref.foo();
        this.ref.bar();
    }
}
```

---

The gist is:

- use `any`, even though you don't want to
- use a non-static getter/setter to both type-check and type-correct in usage